# How to zoom image in flutter while dragging/swipping down?

Tags: flutter

I have one custom image slider and want to zoom the image while the user swipes down/drags down. (I cannot use pinch zoom as the slider moves to the next or prev slide on left-right swipes).

I have tried

1. InteractiveViewer
2. GestureDetector

but can't make it work so far.

I tried also existing libraries for pinch-zoom https://github.com/tkortekaas/pinch_zoom/blob/master/lib/src/pinch_zoom_widget.dart but they work only on pinch obviously and not within sliders.

What I tried was using transformationController and `onVerticalDragUpdate` but couldn't get it to work.

My existing code so far is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DragDownZoomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Duration resetDuration;
  final Function? onZoomStart, onZoomEnd;

  const DragDownZoomWidget({
    required this.child,
    this.resetDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
    this.onZoomStart,
    this.onZoomEnd,
  });

  @override
  _DragDownZoomWidgetState createState() => _DragDownZoomWidgetState();
}

class _DragDownZoomWidgetState extends State<DragDownZoomWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TransformationController _transformationController =
      TransformationController();

  late Animation<Matrix4> _animationReset;
  late AnimationController _controllerReset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllerReset = AnimationController(
      duration: widget.resetDuration,
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerReset.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: double.maxFinite,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          child: widget.child,
          transformationController: _transformationController,
        ),
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
          if (_controllerReset.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
            _animateResetStop();
          } else {
            if (widget.onZoomStart != null) {
              widget.onZoomStart!();
            }
          }
        },
        onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
          _animateResetInitialize();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Go back to static state after resetting has ended
  void _onAnimateReset() {
    _transformationController.value = _animationReset.value;
    if (!_controllerReset.isAnimating) {
      _animationReset.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
      _animationReset = Matrix4Tween().animate(_controllerReset);
      _controllerReset.reset();
      if (widget.onZoomEnd != null) {
        widget.onZoomEnd!();
      }
    }
  }

  /// Start resetting the animation
  void _animateResetInitialize() {
    _controllerReset.reset();
    _animationReset = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: _transformationController.value,
      end: Matrix4.identity(),
    ).animate(_controllerReset);
    _animationReset.addListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _controllerReset.forward();
  }

  /// Stop the reset animation
  void _animateResetStop() {
    _controllerReset.stop();
    _animationReset.removeListener(_onAnimateReset);
    _animationReset = Matrix4Tween().animate(_controllerReset);
    _controllerReset.reset();
  }
}
```

Have to find a way to listen to swipe down/ drag down event and then adjust the animation/transformation accordingly so the image is zoomed. Then on drag end to start animate reset back to the original size

1. How to make _transformationController Matrix4 zoom with a factory of x, example 2 times in a particular place ? I listen to drag down event and want to zoom